# Select/highlight object from ListBox throws error

Tags: vb.net, object, listbox

I have a listbox with some objects. In this case "Persons", something like this:

```
Public Class Person
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Name As string = ""
    Public Email As string = ""

    Public Sub New(ByVal ID As Integer)
        Me.ID = ID
        GetPersonInfo()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetPersonInfo()
        'some stuff gathering info
        Me.Name = 'From some stuff
        Me.Email= 'From some stuff
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "[" & Me.ID & "] " & Me.Name & " - " & Me.Email
    End Function

End Class
```

So far so good. When I load the form, I have a loop adding persons to the listbox, the code looks something like this:

```
For Each UserId As Integer In MyUsersList
    ListBox_Users.Items.Add(New Person(UserId))
Next
```

Nothing strange here. I get a nice list of persons formatted as `[ID] Name - Email` .

How ever, at another place in the program I can select something else, like a Car, for example. The cars are displayed in a ComboBox, and when I change car in this list, I gather info about that car and can then get the email for the car owner. If this email is listed in the ListBox I want to select/highlight this Person in the ListBox automatically. The code for this looks something like this:

```
For Each P As Person In ListBox_Users
    If P.Email = TheEmailRegistredForTheSelectedCar Then
        ListBox_Users.SelectedItem = P
    End If
Next
```

When i run this code, I get the error "The list that this enumerator is bound has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list is not changed."

Well, yes, I can understand there's something fishy about looping a ListBox and in this loop change its selected index, but how should I do it correct in this case?

Edit: Currently I i came up with this code to select the Person in the ListBox, But it feels like there's some better/prettier way to do it?

```
Dim TempPerson As Person
TempPerson = Nothing
For Each P As Person In ListBox_Users
    If P.Email = TheEmailRegistredForTheSelectedCar Then
        TempPerson = P
    End If
Next
If TempPerson Is Nothing Then
    ListBox_Users.ClearSelected()
Else
    ListBox_Users.SelectedItem = TempPerson
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Beware of sintax errors, I didn't try it

```
dim index as integer
dim done as boolean
while not done andalso not index = ListBox_Users.items.count -1
If ListBox_Users.items(index).Email = TheEmailRegistredForTheSelectedCar Then
    done = true
else
    index +=1
End If
end while
if done then
Listbox_Users.selectedindex = index
end if
```

Comment: Ah! Nice thinking to use the index instead of the object. This is almost as my edited solution, but it feels like there's a "nicer" solution to the problem than loop them all and check if there was a match afterwards?

Comment: You could add an owner field to the car pointing to the person object, and then just do Listbox_Users.selecteditem=car.owner. But depending on your code you might not be able to do that

Comment: That is actually a pretty nice solution and it is much more nice to read. It is how ever almost the same problem since I would still need to loop the ListBox and check for an matching email to get a owner for the car, but it's still prettier to set a Person as .Owner for the car. Thx! :-)